# Angular2 scope issue with method

Tags: angular

I have a method in my app that is creating an ActiveX object. Within the response of this method, I have access to the data I need from the site I called.

I am trying to pass that data to a variable defined within the component but for some reason it doesn't have access to it.

**Component:**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

    adminData = [];
    action: string = '';

    test(){

        this.someMethod(
            {
                node: 'loaduserpage_home',
            },
            "http://someSite",
            "GET",
                (msg) => {

                // Create an element we can search though
                let body = document.createElement("div");
                body.innerHTML = msg.match(/<body>[\s\S]+?<\/body>/i);

                // Loop over inputs for demo
                let inputs = body.getElementsByTagName('input');

                // Loop over all inputs in the response and push their field name and value to our array
                for (let index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {
                    this.adminData.push({inputName: inputs[index].name, inputValue: inputs[index].value })
                }

                this.action = 'Search Completed.';

            }, true)

    }

    someMethod(vars, varURL, varMethod, donext, async){
        // creates an active x object
    }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <strong>Data</strong>

    <button (click)="test()" class="btn btn-primary">Run Active X</button>

    <table class="table" *ngIf="adminData.length">
        <thead>
            <th>Input Field Name</th>
            <th>Input Field Value</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let a of adminData">
                <td>{{ a.inputName }}</td>
                <td>{{ a.inputValue }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>
```

If I `console.log(inputs[index].name)`, I have the data I need just fine. However, when I try and push that data to my variable, it doesn't seem to make it.

HOWEVER, if I click this button a second time (after I know the call has been made) the data shows up fine.

Is this a scope issue or a change detection problem?

**Update:**

Seems like this may be an async issue. If I change it to synchronous, the data appears fine (after the browser stopped freezing. However, when async, it doesn't update the data. I wonder if I need to implement a change detection once we know the call is done?

Comment: is there any reason you are using active x object instead of the angular http client?

Comment: @LLai - Legacy tool :/ The website is an internal tool but on another domain so there are cors issues. Since we create the active x object, we have full control of that which is why I needed to go that route.

Comment: I "think" I solved this by adding `this.ref.detectChanges();` after my loop. I assume angular isn't aware of the changes since its out of scope so I had to invoke change detection manually. It seems to now behave as I would expect.

Comment: sounds like it, the xhr request must be out of the angular zone so its not picking up the change detection